# Loading csv file with d3.js v.4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and javascript and can't work out the following.

I'm trying to load a csv file with d3.csv but encountered a problem.

```
d3.csv("data2.csv")
    .row(function (d){
        return {
            ax: Number(d.ax.trim().slice(1)),
            ay: Number(d.ay.trim().slice(1))
        };
    })
    .get(function (error, data){
        console.log(data)
    });
```

My csv file is

```
ax,ay,az 
1,40,50 
2,41,49 
3,39,52 
4,35,49 
5,34,46 
6,33,45 
7,32,42 
8,30,40 
9,29,32 
10,27,26
```

`console.log` is giving me the following:

```
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, columns: Array(3)]
0    :    {ax: 0, ay: 0}
1    :    {ax: 0, ay: 1}
2    :    {ax: 0, ay: 9}
3    :    {ax: 0, ay: 5}
4    :    {ax: 0, ay: 4}
5    :    {ax: 0, ay: 3}
6    :    {ax: 0, ay: 2}
7    :    {ax: 0, ay: 0}
8    :    {ax: 0, ay: 9}
9    :    {ax: 0, ay: 7}
```

The results for `ax` are 0 which is incorrect and `ay` is obviously also incorrect.
How can I get the numbers correct, stored in a array, so that I can continue plotting the data using d3.js version 4?

Comment: Can you provide several lines from the CSV file? The two examples you gave for the the data look different (second one has a space after the ay) so I'm not sure what it really looks like. You could try putting the data into GitHub as a gist, and then forking this JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/karmi/nbw7rsc6/) to get it working for you. A good way to play, and ask for help.

Comment: ax,ay,az
1,40,50
2,41,49
3,39,52
4,35,49
5,34,46
6,33,45
7,32,42
8,30,40
9,29,32
10,27,26

Comment: I put your CSV here: https://gist.github.com/xrd/9a73ccf7ac1e41b728202f3c70cdb959#file-test-csv (raw file https://gist.githubusercontent.com/xrd/9a73ccf7ac1e41b728202f3c70cdb959/raw/9c3a1bde4dee9f0d5f80e705bb4f25353ea6b398/test.csv). The fiddle in the answer below works.

Comment: You might want to update your title to be more clear about what you want to do, it isn't entirely clear from your example what the end goal is, other than properly parsing the CSV file, which I think works as you want here.

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, consider accepting it as the answer by clicking the green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
d3.csv("/data/employees.csv")
  .row(function(d) {
        return {
            age: d.age,
            name: d.name.toUpperCase() // converting name to upper case 
        }; 
   })
  .get(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

[enter link description here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js)

Answer (score 0):

```
d3.csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/xrd/9a73ccf7ac1e41b728202f3c70cdb959/raw/9c3a1bde4dee9f0d5f80e705bb4f25353ea6b398/test.csv')
            .row(function (d){
                console.log( d );
                return {
                    ax: Number(d.ax),
                    ay: Number(d.ay)
                };
            })
            .get(function (error, data){
                console.log(data)
            });
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/g3xfbL9m/9/ and, if you open the console, can see it output to the console with the correct values.